# f:ajax not working inside c:forEach

Tags: jsf

I want to use f:ajax inside c:forEach Tag. But it is not working .

```
<c:forEach var="fact" items="#{factBean.nodeHierarchy}" varStatus="status">
  <h:inputText value="#{factBean.month}" > 
        <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{factBean.saveFactValue}"/> 
  </h:inputText>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I make it workable ? If i place the h:inputText outside c:forEach then it works perfectly.
But my textbox are dynamic and they will be generated inside the c:forEach tag block.

Comment: Works for me in a completely blank page of a playground project using latest Mojarra version with everything set to default. Which JSF impl/version are you using? Tried the lastest?

Comment: Are you sure you don't use `var` of foreach inside `h:inputText`?